# swift how to reload tableview selected row(.checkmark) values from sqlite

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uitableview

The selected row(.checkmark) values(strings) of a tableview are saved in sqlite DB and tableview has to be reloaded with same values, also displaying check marks. Code snippet given below

```
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print("selected  \(arr[indexPath.row])")

        if let cell = medTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            if cell.selected {
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark

            }
        }

        if let selectedrows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {

            print("didDeselectRowAtIndexPath selected rows:\(selectedrows)")

            let objRegisterModel: RegisterModel = RegisterModel()

            medicationFor = "\(selectedrows)"
            objRegisterModel.MedicationFor = medicationFor;


            let splitString = objRegisterModel.MedicationFor.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

            print("getSelectedrowsValues", splitString)


        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print("deselected  \(arr[indexPath.row])")

        if let cell = medTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }

        if let sr = medTable.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            print("didDeselectRowAtIndexPath selected rows:\(sr)")
        }
    }
```

On reloading tableview, values are displayed but not checkmarks

```
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = medTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(intervalCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.accessoryType = .None
        cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.row]

        let objRegisterModel: RegisterModel = RegisterModelManager.getDBInstance().getRegisterDataByCurrentMedID(uid)

        if objRegisterModel != "" {

            medicationFor = objRegisterModel.MedicationFor
        }


        return cell
    }
```

The saved values in sqliteDB are shown below

```
**[<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}]**
```

Comment: Show us your tableView(tableView:UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) method.

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            
            return arr.count
        }

Comment: And what are the values stored in the arr array?

Comment: @RajeshM Did any of solutions below helped you?

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cellN:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell();
        if let isChecked == true{
            cellN.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        }else{
            cellN.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        }
        return cell
}
```

You need to check condition in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method to show/hide checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the `cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark` in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

and `cell.accessoryType = .None` in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

This will make sure checkmarks are shown on selection and hidden on deselection.

But in case of table view reload, the data source method  `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` is called, there you have only added `cell.accessoryType = .None'`

If you need to display check marks properly call below code snippet, which from my understanding read data from DB, before setting accessoryType

```
let objRegisterModel: RegisterModel = RegisterModelManager.getDBInstance().getRegisterDataByCurrentMedID(uid)

    if objRegisterModel != "" {

        medicationFor = objRegisterModel.MedicationFor
    }
```

and then put a condition accordingly

```
if (informationShownSelectedinDB) {
    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = .None
}
```

Comment: Thanks..@DILi, @Harsh Shah & El Tomato  I'll check and post the result shortly